# Create a temp column for an aggregation

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I am creating the following (temporary) column for an aggregation:

```
df['count_of_source_videos'] = np.where(df['is_main_video'] & df['file_name'].str.contains('DIGITAL_SOURCE'), 1, 0)
```

And then the aggregation part:

```
summary_df = df.groupby(['provider', 'id']).agg(
  num_source_videos = ('count_of_source_videos', 'sum'),
).reset_index()
```

With the above approach, the column `count_of_source_videos` stays there permanently. Is there a way to do the aggregation without adding the new column? If so, how could that be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.rename()` on the existing column instead of creating a new column:

```
df['count_of_source_videos'] = np.where(df['is_main_video'] &
                                 df['file_name'].str.contains('DIGITAL_SOURCE'),
                                 1, 0)
summary_df = (df.groupby(['provider', 'id'])['count_of_source_videos'].sum()
                .rename('num_source_videos').reset_index())
```

or a one-liner:

```
summary_df = (df.assign(count_of_source_videos=
                        np.where(df['is_main_video'] &
                                 df['file_name'].str.contains('DIGITAL_SOURCE'),
                                 1, 0))
                .groupby(['provider', 'id'])['count_of_source_videos'].sum()
                .rename('num_source_videos').reset_index())
```

Comment: I see, what about not having the first line at all and doing the function within the `(...)`, or is that not possible?

Comment: @David542 the way that I have done it requires a column that already exists to be summed. You can make this a "one-liner" with `.assign` though:

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
s = df['is_main_video'] & df['file_name'].str.contains('DIGITAL_SOURCE')
summary_df = s.groupby([df.provider, df.id]).agg(num_source_videos = 'sum').reset_index()
```

If you don't want to create a temp series `s`, you may chain it, but it will be less readable

```
summary_df = ((df['is_main_video'] & df['file_name'].str.contains('DIGITAL_SOURCE'))
                      .groupby([df.provider, df.id])
                      .agg(num_source_videos = 'sum').reset_index())
```